# Should we check for view visibility in Presenter or Activity in MVP pattern?

Tags: android, mvp

so, i am following MVP pattern and i am delegating every view task to presenter, just the way it should be done

for ex. :

```
@Override
public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture, int i, int i1) {
    if(textureView.getVisibility != View.GONE)        
        mPresenter.onSurfaceTextureAvailable(surfaceTexture);
}
```

i wanted to know if checking for the visibility of a view directly like this inside my activity(which is the View in MVP) is permitted?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`View` layer has responsibility to only display views to user. It does not have business logic. `Presenter` layer responsible for presenting data from Model to View layer. It handles background task, invokes operations on model and setting data in view. You should check it in your `Activity` like this.

```
public class YourActivity extends BaseActivity implements MainMvpView {

@Inject YourPresenter yourPresenter;

......


@Override
public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture, int i, int i1) {
    if(textureView.getVisibility != View.GONE)        
        mPresenter.onSurfaceTextureAvailable(surfaceTexture);
}

......

}
```

Comment: i am doing exactly like what you have said,
my question is if the checking of visibility of a view is something that a View should have responsibility of.

Comment: yes, because of the visual interaction with the user

Comment: if you want to test this case the logic should not be in the view ! , I am not agree with @EgeKuzubasioglu . But it depents of you and your logic!